# Binding to a value of a string property

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Is there anyway to bind to the value of a property, not property itself.
For example: There is a generic grid with two columns "Name" and "Code"

In viewmodel:

```
NameMemberPath = "Title";       // fetch from database
CodeMemberPath = "ProductCode"; // fetch from database
```

In Xaml:

```
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn UniqueName="Name" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=NameMemberPath}" />
<telerik:GridViewDataColumn UniqueName="Code" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=CodeMemberPath}" />
```

How to bind the Name to "Title" insted of NameMemberPath

It's possible to do it programmatically but I need to do it declaratively!

Comment: I guess you want to create a dynamic binding?

Comment: Can you please explain why you want to bind a variable than a property?

Comment: I believe NameMemberPath is a property Becuase it's pascal case! Accordings to c# coding style.

Comment: 1st: There is a better way to find out if it's a Propery. Just go to the definition of it (press F12 in VS) and look if has a `get` and `set` Methods. 2nd: what do you mean with bind name to title?

Comment: @MartinHoratschek he want to create a generic Binding so `DataMemberBinding="{Binding Path=NameMemberPath}"` should be converted `Binding="{Binding Title}"`

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest to change your concept because the ViewModel should provides the Properties for the View directly

let's suggest you want a generic View which will bind to a Property `MyAnyProb` so it is now to problem of your ViewModel to present this Property.

your ViewModel does now his job by providing this property

```
    public object MyAnyProb
    {
        get { return getMagic(); }
        set { setMagic(value); }
    }

    // and her is the part where you need to add your logic
    private object getMagic()
    {
        // let magic happen
    }
    private void setMagic(object probValue)
    {
        // other magic
    }
```

now you are able to use your view generic with no worries about the property because your generic ViewModel will take care about it

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
var MyStrings = new List<string>();
MyStrings = MyFunctionToRetrieveAListOfStrings();

foreach(var str in MyStrings)
{
 Binding binding = new Binding("YourControlValue");
 binding.Source = str;
 YourControl.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, binding)
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742863.aspx

Answer (score 0):

No you always bind a `DependencyProperty` to a (`public`) Property.
[image: Binding]
<sub>(source: [microsoft.com](http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC93033.png))</sub>

Read more about Binding in the [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/data-binding-overview?redirectedfrom=MSDN#fbid=I80P1eaziJ-)!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you cannot do that in xaml. How about adding columns to your telerik grid from code behind? I am not very sure if this solution is feasible to you or not but worth a try.

```
GridViewDataColumn column = new GridViewDataColumn();
column.DataMemberBinding = new Binding(CodeMemberPath.ToString());
this.yourTelerikGrid.Columns.Add(column);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use the "SetBinding" method.

```
TextBlock myTextBlock = new TextBlock();
myTextBlock.SetBinding(TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding("SomePropertyName"));
```

That should do the trick